# filemtime(): stat failed for

Tags: php

Пытаюсь получить время последнего изменения html-файлов для скрипта, генерирующего карту сайта.

Пробовала так:

```
$last = filemtime($str_url);
```

Или так:

```
$tim = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($str_url));
```

И постоянно получаю вот такие ошибки для каждого url из проверяемого массива:

```
PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for https://site.ru in /var/www/.../.../.../site.ru/src/sitemap14.php on line 247   

January 01 1970 03:00:00.PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/.../.../.../site.ru/base.html in /var/www/.../.../.../site.ru/src/sitemap14.php on line 247            

January 01 1970 03:00:00.PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for /var/www/.../.../.../site.ru/base1.html in /var/www/.../.../.../site.ru/src/sitemap14.php on line 247
```

В этой 247 строке как раз:

```
$tim = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime($str_url));
```

Переменная $str_url - типа string, как и необходимо для функции filemtime();
Сама переменная выводится (проверяла `print_r($str_url)`)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как ее исправить?

Спасибо.

P.S. Уточнила насчет необходимых прав. Ответили, что никие дополнительные права в моем случае не нужны.

Переменная $str_url содержит результат функции strval($url) - строковые значения урлов сайта вида: /var/www/логин_у_хостера/data/www/site.ru/имя_файла

**P.P.S.** В качестве эксперимента попробовала написать так:

```
$tim = date ("F d Y H:i:s.", @filemtime($str_url)
```

В результате получила для каждого значения переменной, кроме последних 2: January 01 1970 03:00:00. А для последних двух - реальное время изменения файлов: April 29 2019 00:03:41.
April 14 2019 19:13:31.

Чудеса с этой filemtime()...

Comment: Уверены, что путь к файлу верно прописан? Какой тип ссылки - абсолютная или относительная?

Comment: Покажите что содержится в $str_url. @Marionette правильно подметил, проблема в ссылке.

Comment: Проверьте права на папки и файлы. ну и конечно -же существование самих фаилов и правильность написания адреса =)

Comment: Пути к файлам прописаны верно. В $str_url лежат пути вида, который приводится в тексте ошибки. Названия файлов в ошибке отображаются, значит, скрипт их "видит". А, вот, права для скрипта надо проверить, да.

Comment: в тексте ошибки у вас какие-то фрагменты с `...`, что не дает представления о конкретном пути и правильности его указания. А то что названия файлов отображаются в ошибке дак это вообще никак не связано с тем, что скрипт "видит" файл, это входящая строка, и никак не зависит от того есть сам файл  или нет.

Comment: @Наталья, попробуйте указать относительный путь к файлам

Comment: Всякие пробовала. И относительные тоже.  ... - это я написала здесь в вопросе для сокращения примера кода

Comment: noname2019, дополнила вопрос - указала, что содержится в переменной $str_url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[тут пишут:](https://php.ru/manual/function.filemtime.html)

> int filemtime ( string $filename )
>
> Данная функция возвращает время последней записи `блоков файла`, иначе
>   говоря, изменения содержания `файла`.

Речь идёт о файле. А в вашей ошибке речь о веб-странице:

> PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed for https://site.ru in /var/www/...

Как вы знаете, этой страницы физически не существует на сервере, она генерируется php на момент запроса. Значит и данных о времени её изменения нет. Это, кстати, можно проверить, чекая `http-заголовок` ответа [Last-Modified](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-last-modified/) (его сервер отсылает с другими заголовками в ответ на запрос файла):

```
$headers = get_headers('https://www.php.net/images/logos/php-logo.svg', 1); // file
echo 'get_headers ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($headers['Last-Modified']));
// 2017-04-19 18:20:03

$headers = get_headers('https://php.ru/manual/wrappers.http.html', 1); // web page
echo 'get_headers ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($headers['Last-Modified']));
// Notice: Undefined index: Last-Modified 
// 1970-01-01 03:00:00
```

Поэтому вы, делая так `@filemtime($str_url),` получали `January 01 1970 03:00:00`. Вы подовляли вывод шибок `filemtime` с помощью оператора **[@](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)**, и `date()` вам показывал время начала [эпохи Линух](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) (ну, и +3ч на часовой пояс вашего сервера). А вот последние два - я полагаю - файлы, по ним вы получили верные значения.

Вариант для вас - [кешировать](https://catswhocode.com/phpcache/) страницы. В таком случае на первый запрос `https://site.ru` будет создаваться физический `html` файл. Единственный минус - необходимость очистки кешей после каждого изменения контента, руками или скриптом.

Если сайт на WP и прочих - ищите екстеншены, решающие подобные вопросы.

Comment: Кирилл, Вы абсолютно правы.Я тоже только что поняла, что пытаюсь получить данные о несуществующих html, когда на сервере лежат php-файлы. Страницы у меня кэшируются для снижения нагрузки на хостинг. Кэш очищается по расписанию. Нужно просто в скрипте подключать хтмл-файлы из папки "кэш". Огромное Вам спасибо! Ваш профессионализм вызывает большое уважение! Про кэш я бы сама еще неделю не могла сообразить.